# Do zombie testifacates naturally spawn like regular zombies in Minecraft xbox 360 edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Do zombie villagers in the Xbox 360 edition spawn randomly or does there have to be villagers in the world originally

Answer (score 2):

As of [TU14](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition_version_history#xbox-TU14), Zombie Villagers are part of console edition.

[From the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_villager#Variants):

> Zombie villagers comprise 5% of all spawned zombies. They behave as ordinary zombies, but their character model's head and face is reminiscent of that of a villager, shaded with a darker green hue.
>
> Zombie villagers can also result from zombie attacks on villagers. If any type of zombie kills a villager, there is a chance that the villager will transform into a zombie villager (100% on hard difficulty, 50% on normal, 0% on easy).

Zombie villagers will spawn in worlds where there are no villagers.

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago, Zombie Testificates were added in an update to the XBox 360 (I don't have it for PC, so I was super psyched when I first saw this).

Comment: Do you know the exact release number?